# Expand Angular Material expansion table row via TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-datatables

I am using an Angular Material expansion datatable that I modified from the docs, [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/paexomjyaby). I refresh the data in the table when a change is made. This works fine, but the table fully collapses to its default state after the refresh, creating an undesirable user experience.

I would like to force the previously open row to expand after the refresh. I have yet to find anyway to forcefully expand the rows from TypeScript. Below is my method that gets called when a table refresh occurs:

```
  refresh() {
    this.refreshDatatable();
    // I want to forcefully open the previously expanded row HERE.
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could keep the open tab's index in a property `currentOpenTab` (for example) and re open it after data has changed.

Comment: @Baruch That is exactly what I am trying to do. I can grab the index easily, I just don't know how to expand the panel. I have no issue getting the row via the expandedElement variable. I would assume I would need to set [@detailExpand] to 'expanded', but I don't know how in TypeScript as it exists within the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example allowing you to extend a default table row.
I hope this will help you.
You will only need to retrieve the index from the tab previously opened in your data list.

TS:

```
export class TableExpandableRowsExample implements OnInit {
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position'];
  expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.expandedElement = ELEMENT_DATA[2];
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
    <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
      <div class="example-element-diagram">
        <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
        <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
        <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
        <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
      </div>
      <div class="example-element-description">
        {{element.description}}
        <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

**[StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-expand-angular-material-expansion-table-row-ts?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)**

DEMO:

[image]

Comment: Okay this works. I was accidentally trying to perform **this.expandedElement = this.expandedElementCopy**. That doesn't work as it is not a deep copy. Thank you for your help!